# Swift 4: Is there a more concise way to check for nil than what is in this tutorial?

Tags: swift

Just learning here but there HAS to be a better way to write the code below because in this class I have 102 datapoints and I really don't want each to be a 3 liner. The examples I found with Google use let or var and I couldn't find any with self.

```
if snap["id"] !== nil {
   self.id = snap["id"] as! Int
}
```

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide : The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) (section *Optional Binding*)

Comment: I don't know which tutorial it is, but I can guarentee that with examples like this, it's crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if value is nil also like this:

```
if let id = snap["id"] as? Int {
    // if this gets executed, id is not nil
}
```

or even like this

```
guard let id = snap["id"] as? Int else {
    // in case this executes, id is nil
    return
}

// From here on, you can use id constant, it's value is not nil
```

If you are using second code, in case snap["id"] is nil, code will return and anything after return won't be executed. It depends on the case which code to use, both ways are possible.

**EDIT**
In case you still need to use variable, you can assign it some default value, in case it is nil:

```
let id = snap["id"] as? Int ?? 0 // in this case, if "id" is nil, we assign a value of 0
```

Comment: but these are using self. and not let, because the variable was initialized before the class

Comment: in this case, use: `self.id = snap["id"] as? Int ?? 0` or something like that. Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original value, if the value in the dictionary is `nil`, you can simply:

```
self.id = (snap["id"] as? Int) ?? self.id
```

or

```
(dict["id"] as? Int).map { self.id = $0 }
```

Comment: There's a downside to abusing map like this: if this code is being called in an initializer, than you would get a compilation error for trying to implicitly capture `self` before all fields were initialized.

Comment: @Alexander I don't think I am abusing `map` but you are right about the `init` problem. However, I am explicitly mentioning that such code is for cases when you want to keep the initial value as in the OP's original code, therefore I am assuming that `id` already has some value.

Comment: @Sluthan I definitely think it's abuse but I'm okay with it. On the other hand, lots of the functional programming purists would crucify you for using a map with a side effect, and not even using the return result. it's being used as an `ifPresent`, essentially. I would definitely opt for an `if let` in this case, for a more universal approach

Comment: @Alexander I would use `if let` too :)

Comment: Although, declaring a special `?=` operator for that is also a possibility (which I would not use personally). https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170123/030830.html